# Creating static library and linking to it with premake

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, static-libraries, premake

I am currently trying to learn how to use premake 4 in order to apply it to the OpenGL [sdk](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/). I am currently trying to make a Visual Studio 2010 solution that constructs 2 projects, one being a static library, the other contains a single main source file, with the main method.

This project is extremely simple, and is solely for the purpose of learning premake. In the static library project, named Test, I have 2 files, Test.h and Test.cpp. Test.h contains the prototype for the method print(). print() simply prints a line to the console. Using premake, I linked the static library to the Main project, and in main.cpp I have included the Test.h file. My problem is this: in VS2010 I get this error when I attempt to build:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl print(void)" (? print@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main  
1>.\Main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

Here is my code in the 4 files, the premake4.lua:

```
solution "HelloWorld"
    configurations {"Debug", "Release"}
project "Main"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"
    files{
        "main.cpp"

    }
    configuration "Debug"
        defines { "DEBUG" }
        flags { "Symbols" }

    configuration "Release"
        defines { "NDEBUG" }
        flags { "Optimize" } 
    links {"Test"}
project "Test"
    kind "StaticLib"
    language "C++"
    files{
        "test.h",
        "test.cpp"

    }
```

Test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

void print(){
    std::cout << "HELLO" << std::endl;
}
```

Test.h:

```
void print();
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include "test.h"
int main(){
    print();
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

If you are wondering why there is a getch() there, on my computer the console immediately closes once it reaches return 0, so I use getch() to combat that issue, which forces the window to wait until the user has pressed another key. Any advice on this issue would be wonderful, because I simply am not sure what the problem is. If it is something simple please dont castrate me on it, I have very little experience with premake and static libraries, which is why I am trying to learn them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
links {"Test"}
```

Lua is not Python. Whitespace is irrelevant to Lua, just like whitespace doesn't matter to C++. So your `links` statement only applies to the `"Release"` configuration. If you want it to apply to the project as a whole, it needs to go before the `configuration` statement, just like your `kind`, `files`, and other commands.

Premake4 works this way so that you could have certain libraries that are only used in a `"Release"` build (or Debug or whatever). Indeed, you can put almost *any* `project` command under a `configuration`. So you can have specific files that are used only in a debug build, or whatever.

Comment: That was the problem, however now i get a problem when I try to run the build, a popup which says: Unable to start program: 'file_location\.\Test.lib' The specified file is in an unrecognized or unsupported binary format. Any help with this? PS. What I changed was move Links {"Test"} to right below Language.

Comment: @user1032369: That's because you're trying to run the *library*, not the executable. Change the current "Startup Project".

Comment: So I can only run premake programs by clicking the executable, i cant just run it from VS?

Comment: @user1032369: Visual Studio has the concept of a "Startup Project". This is the project that will be executed when you attempt to execute something from Visual Studio. You can *change* what the current startup project is by right-clicking on it in the list of projects. This has nothing to do with Premake.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed. Sorry, I have only used VS for about a month, and I do not know each little part of it. Thanks for the help.